# Bounds are not valid

Tags: leaflet

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin and I'm facing an issue.

When the map is loaded without no markers everything work right.

But when I'm loading a layer and trying to make the map fitbounds it telling me 'Bounds are not valid'. Without any information. What the hell ? Can't check if bounds are valid bc it seem that isValid() does not exist.

Every markers are in an array and the group is made like this :

```
var group = L.featureGroup(markerArray).addTo(map);
```

then

```
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {padding: L.point(20, 20)});
```

and this last line seem to make an error

Comment: And what's the value of `group.getBounds()`?

Comment: It seem to be an empty object, don't know why, on my localhost ther's coordinates in it. However the js console is telling me that 't is null', from leaflet.js.

Comment: Use `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js`, and set up breakpoints to debug your data. How many markers in the group?

Comment: only one marker actually in the group.

Comment: I'll try to debug it with leaflet-src.js . But the fact that error are showing up only in distant give me big headaches